# Condition insuring a convex body is a ball

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a convex centered body in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and suppose that for every $\theta\in{S^{n-1}}$ we have $|K\cap{\theta^{\perp}}|=C$. Does this imply that $K$ is the euclidian ball?

One can consider a refinement of the first version, assuming moreover that all such sections are identical. Is it now the euclidian ball?

BTW, centered means that $\int_{K}xdx=0$

Thanks.

Comment: Probably true. There is an older book that might be a good intro, although in German. https://archive.org/details/kreisundkugel00blasgoog

Comment: Thanks  orangeskid, but I can't read German. Are you familiar with any other mass on this topic?

Comment: I took a brief look at the contents but could not find a corresponding result. Still it seems very plausible. We assume $\dim \ge 3$ and all the sections are again balls, right? I can't think of another reference at the moment. An interesting problem.

Comment: I don't see why the dimension has to be larger then 2, and the sections can be anything, the only requirement is that every two sections are identical.

Comment: Oh, I see. So in $\dim 2$ all the chords have the same length.

Comment: Quite so. Note that if we assume symmetry of the body, it is immediate.